# Center of Mass/ Center of Gravity

Tags: calculus

Find the center of gravity of the region between $y = x + 2$, $y = –3x + 6$, and $y = (2 – x)/3$. In general, how do you find the center of gravity of a region determined by three curves such as in this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

the three lines have 3 intersection points A,B and C.

then

$$3\vec {OG}=\vec {OA}+\vec {OB}+\vec {OC} $$

with

$A (1,3) , B (-1,1) $ and $C (2,0) $

Answer (score 1):

In general, the center of mass of a region $D$ in the $xy$ plane which constant density $\delta$ is given by the following coordinates:

$$x_c=\frac{1}{M} \iint_{D} \delta x dA=\frac{1}{A} \iint_{D} x dA$$

$$y_c=\frac{1}{M} \iint_{D} \delta x dA=\frac{1}{A} \iint_{D} x dA$$

This comes directly from the physics definition of the center of mass of an object composed of point masses $m_i$:

$$x_c=\frac{1}{M} \sum m_ix_i$$

$$y_c=\frac{1}{M} \sum m_iy_i$$

And by the fact that for sheets in the $xy$ plane we have $\delta=\frac{M}{A}$ for constant $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks but this comment does not answer the question.

Comment: This does actually answer the question which was how, you failed to show any work or thoughts on the problem yourself so we have no bearing on what will help you.

Comment: I can set it up for you and evaluate, but it is common practice on mse not to do that if the asker has not shown any work or their own thoughts. Judging by your previous questions, I think you are more than capable of setting up the double integral. If you are not, let me know and show me an attempt at setting it up, and I will follow through @EricBrown

Comment: This problem does not require a double integral. I am tutoring a student who is doing this problem in single-variable calculus: the applications of the integral (finding the center of gravity problems). He does not even know how to evaluate a double integral, so I need the solution in single-variable calculus and NOT multi-variable calculus.

Comment: Then in that case the student is likely to be expected to use the formulas here. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CenterOfMass.aspx. Only now the top, bottom functions need to be defined piece wisely.

Comment: Then what is the piece-wise definition of the top and bottom functions. How in general do I write these definitions for three intersecting functions?

Comment: The top function is $x+2$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $y=-3x+6$ for $1 \leq x \leq 2$. The bottom function is $y=\frac{2-x}{3}$. One would have to graph the function and see that it is precisely what it tells you. If you don't know where to "split the function up" look where it naturally splits up into different equations.

Comment: Also the domain of interest of the bottom function is $[-1,2]$ but to make it compatible with the integration we split it into $[-1,1]$ and $[1,2]$.

Comment: Thanks. You answered my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61011/discussion-between-eric-brown-and-ahmed-s-attaalla).